# Android : How to avoid header from scrolling in listview , android?

Tags: android, listview, header

I have a list view , where i am adding headerview to that list . every thing fine , but when am scrolling list headerview also moving with list, so i want to avoid headerview scrolling , i mean i have to scroll only list when i list reached to topview (titlebar), headerview has to remain bottom of titlebar .

can any one gimme a solution for this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of a header use the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      --> Your header layout here           
    </LinearLayout>

  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Important things to notice:

- The id of the ListView must be `@android:id/list` in order to be able to use a ListActivity
- Use a 0 height and set the weight to 1

Comment: for one header , its good one. but if i had , differnt list patterns for same listview. i have given a headerview for each pattern

Comment: One question is, how to align the header with its underline data?

Comment: That works.  But it seems very odd to me that the listview can have a header and footer that scroll away.  Its hard to think of a use case where you would want them to scroll.  I'd like to see a new attribute added to the ListView that locks the header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked fine when i included a tag called `<include>` before my listview,
the code was something like this

```
<include layout="@layout/stationlist_header"/>
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctly understand what you ask.
So I get you have something like.

```
<ListView>
<Header />
<Item />
<Item />
<Item />
</ListView>
```

Why don't you do

```
<Header />
<ListView>
<Item />
<Item />
<Item />
</ListView>
```

?

Comment: for one header , its good idea. but if i had , differnt list patterns for same listview. i have given a headerview for each pattern

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a Header view add the view directly to the layout above the list view.
I had implemented all my list view like this all of them work grt..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


 <ImageView android:id="@+id/title_top_refine_search" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="45dip"
                      android:src="@drawable/title_bar_top"
                      android:scaleType="fitXY"
                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
            </ImageView>  


        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                  android:textStyle="bold"  android:gravity="center" android:textSize="23dip"
                  android:text="Refine Search"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView> 

        <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/title_top_refine_search" 
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"> </ListView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

A Layout Sample Containing header view and List view below