# How to make ListView header static

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need my header in the listview to be unscrollable. I have tried with addHeaderView but of no use. I don't want this to be done using a Vertical LinearLayout, with a fixed textview and listView inside it.

I have to make the header of ListView static(unscrollable)

Any solution for this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: dude now see my output header + listview

Answer (score 2):

You could just place the header above the listview in a linearlayout

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply man..but this solution, I had already mentioned there in my question itself. I dont want to use a linear layout and an additional textview here.Is there any possible way to make the listview header itself static?

Comment: I'm sorry i read over the 'don't' part in your question. I believe the whole point of the listheader is to be scrollable with the listview, so i don't think there is a way to do what you want but i'm not 100% sure about this. I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274519/android-how-to-avoid-header-from-scrolling-in-listview-android) link which also leads to placing a seperate UI element above the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a realy nice solution, but what you can try and will give you the effect you wnat.
Is align your listView to an LinearLayout.

Comment: Hello Maikel..thanks for your reply.Could u please make it more clear?..is this the same solution which I had already mentioned in the question itself??.Keeping the textview(header) and the listView in the LinerLayout.Is that what you exactly mean by aligning the listView to linearlayout??But I need to meake the header of ListView itself static without using linerlayout or textview.

Comment: Create a LinearLayout , in that layout you add your textview, design it how ever you want. Then align the top of your listview at the bottom of your LinearLayout.

Comment: thanks...but the same thing only man...which I had already mentioned in my question :) :) Any other alternative?